# PHP MySQL - Selecting from large tables in order

Tags: php, mysql, select

Basically I have a traffic exchange site and since it's becoming quite popular now it's displaying each users sites much less often than before.

There are over 17,000 sites in the traffic exchange and they are ranked in order of **CPC**.  **CPC** stands for cost per click which is how many site points they are willing to spend per click to their site.  This ranges from **1-10**.

Each site is viewed for **20** seconds so for all **17,000** sites to be viewed once it will take absolutely ages so they only receive like **1** exchange a day..

Basically what I'm after is a way to select sites from the DB which makes it more fair for users who set their sites to a **lower CPC**.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: can you please rephrase `Basically what I'm after is a way to select sites from the DB which makes it more far for users who set their sites to a lower CPC.`?

Comment: My guess is he means that he wants an order by CPC descending.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to select sites from the database which will make it more fair for users who set their sites to a lower CPC.  So those sites that have a CPC of 2 or a lower number will get more views.

Comment: can you post some code examples of the tables involved?